# Why is this value from a CSV file being altered when adding to SQL via Coldfusion?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion-10

I have a CSV file that I have made into a readable Query with Coldfusion.  The csv file has two pieces of data that I want to update into a permanent table (MS SQL) with a unique reference of a product sku.

One of the values has a '%' sign, so I stripped it and loaded the value into a variable.  The other value I loaded into a variable because it's also experiencing a problem.

On each iteration of a query loop, I run the following code to move line by line through the CSV.

```
<cfset VARIABLE.noPercentageSign = ReReplace(qGetSalesData.qOverall,'%','','ALL')>
<cfset VARIABLE.quantitySold = qGetSalesData.qQty>
#qGetSalesData.qSKU#, #VARIABLE.quantitySold#, #VARIABLE.noPercentageSign#<br />

<cfquery name="qUpdateRecord">
  UPDATE orderbot_inv_details
  SET 
    overallSales = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DECIMAL" scale="2" value="#VARIABLE.noPercentageSign#">,
    totalSales = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#VARIABLE.quantitySold#">  
  WHERE productSku = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#qGetSalesData.qSKU#">
</cfquery>
```

When I output the data before loading it up, I get the SKU name, I get a value of units sold and then I get the margin.  These values displaying on screen match perfectly.

When they get loaded into the database, the numbers are way out in left field.

For example, the very first line is 1679 units with a margin of 3.45 (percentage already stripped).  However, the values entered into the database are 61 and .45.  (Every single item entered is completely wrong, and it's just a coincidence in this case that .45 is the last two digits of actual value, in every case, the number is way out there).

In the database, those fields are integer and decimal(8,2).

Here's what I've tried:

-Hard coding in 1679 & 3.45 in the query values.  This works, every value gets changed to those exactly.

-Actually changing them in the DB, no problem.

-Putting these items in a Val() function, same result.

-Updating only one of the fields at at time.  Still get the same incorrect values.

I feel as if these steps eliminate SQL being the issue, it seems like something wrong with ColdFusion.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this query?  I've updated items through a basic query like this in ColdFusion thousands of times, and I've never experienced this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177743/discussion-between-tim-howey-and-ageax).